# php curl post request

Tags: php, post, curl, request

I wrote this code to send a post request

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.exemple.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "PHPSESSID=32chars; prsess_******=32chars; login_******=55chars");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("type" => "1"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
print $head = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);}
curl_close($ch);
```

But I'm getting this as a header

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 ...
Host: www.exemple.com
Accept: */*
Referer: http://www.exemple.com/page.php
Cookie: PHPSESSID=32chars; prsess_******=32chars; login_******=55chars
Content-Length: 140
Expect: 100-continue
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8; boundary=----------------------------0636ec3c1d17
```

Can someone tell me why `type=1` is not listed?

Answer (score 6):

The POST variables are sent in the body of the request, this is not part of the headers.

The body of the request is sent just after the headers, separated by a blank line.

BTW when you set CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS as an array, curl is sending the body as multipart/form-data, and it sets the Content-Type to multipart/form-data accordingly.

You should not set the `Content-Type` header yourself, as it breaks the request.

Or set CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS as a string (e.g. `http_build_query(array('type' => 1));`) to avoid curl from sending POST as multipart/form-data.

Comment: And how to get the body of the request?

Comment: @キューゾ リファイ AFAIK you can't. Why do you need to?

Comment: Try setting CURLOPT_VERBOSE to true, if you want this for debug purposes

Comment: I want to check what I'm sending

Comment: Any idea how to check the body of the request? because I'm not getting the right response from the host

Comment: I have to or else I won't get a response from the host

Comment: Then try setting CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS as a string: `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('type' => 1)))`

Comment: I think the problem here is that the `Content-Type:` header doesn't match the content - I think the body is multipart and the header is not. Do this: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8"));`

Comment: That's what I was saying :) (+1 for wireshark)

Comment: I can't find my modem in the capture interfaces, i'm using a sagem fast 800

Answer (score 2):

POST data is sent in the body of the request, not in the headers.

Answer (score 1):

POST fields are not included in the header, they are included in the body.

cURL is waiting for the server to respond with a `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` message before it sends the body, because it has sent a `Expect: 100-continue` header.

Is there more code missing from your question? Because the `Content-Length: 140` header is wrong if there isn't (should be 6)...

Comment: What are the chars that are counted?

Comment: The length of the body, i.e. `type=1`. This is 6 characters, so it should be `Content-Length: 6`. Why do you need to get the request? Surely what you need is the response?

Comment: I want to check what I'm sending

Comment: @DaveRandom the POST is sent as multipart/form-data, so with boundaries and headers this could make 140 bytes

Comment: You need to use a packet capture program like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) if you want to know for definite what is being transmitted across the network.

Comment: @arnaud yeh I thought that, because there is a `boundary=...` in the header, but if you look the actual MIME type sent (and the one set in the code) is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This may be a cURL bug...

Comment: That's because OP sets the Content-Type header (`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: ...`); I think curl sets just appends the boundary when the content-type is already set

Comment: @arnaud So where does the extra length in the body come from? The print of the headers says MIME type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the `Content-Length` says otherwise...